# PHP-MySQL - Destroy/Disregard Table Fields if it contains no value/null

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-in, sql-null

Good day! I was trying to LEFT Join one Table into Another. Is it possible to destroy or disregard table fields, for example `blotter_entry` if it doesn't contain any value or if it is `null`? By looking at the screenshot below, As you can see I have three tables with `blotter_entry` . Then it really depends on the user or `res_id` if the user belongs to the `tbl_complainant as tc` or `tbl_respondent as te`, or `tbl_victim as tv`.

In the screen shot, the query found that the `blotter_entry` is found in `tbl_complainant`, How can I disregard the two `blotter_entry` from `tbl_respondent and tbl_victim`?

I ask this because when ever I loop this SQL Query and do a `echo $row['blotter_entry']` to display it in the website, because if the `res_id` is detected and found it `tbl_respondent and tbl_victim` it will not display anything in the webpage. For example `res_id` is number 3, and he is a respondent/victim. Whenever I output the `echo $row['blotter_entry']` in the website. It will not show anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[Screenshot after running this SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6flwh.png)

```
SELECT tr.res_id
     , tc.res_id
     , tc.blotter_entry
     , te.res_id
     , te.blotter_entry
     , tv.res_id
     , tv.blotter_entry
     , tb.blotter_id
     , tb.blotter_type
     , tb.blotter_reporteddate
     , tb.blotter_reportedtime
     , tb.blotter_incidentdate
     , tb.blotter_incidenttime
     , tb.blotter_status
     , tc.complainant_name
     , te.respondent_name
     , tv.victim_name
  FROM tbl_resident tr
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_complainant tc 
    on tr.res_id = tc.res_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_respondent te 
    on tr.res_id = te.res_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_victim tv 
    on tr.res_id = tv.res_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_blotter tb 
    on tc.blotter_entry = tb.blotter_entry 
    OR te.blotter_entry = tb.blotter_entry 
    OR tv.blotter_entry = tb.blotter_entry
 WHERE tr.res_id = 1;
```

Comment: Did you try to ignore the `NULL` values? read more about [SQL NULL Values](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

Comment: And notice that `res_id` is an `ambiguous column name`

Comment: @BurhanKashour I did. But it doesn't solve the problem, I'm trying to learn MySQL and I've hit a dead end which it this one.

Comment: I don't really get what you need, but probably it's COALESCE() function

Comment: The problem you face is an `ambiguous column name` Which is null in some tables, try to add [aliases](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) inside your query to separate between the columns !

Comment: I'm getting the right results that I want. To simplify, I just want to Ignore null results in MySQL JOIN queries. Like if theres a null value. simply remove it or put them all to the right >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: If you don't want to select any column, why not simply remove it from the list of columns in your query?

Comment: @YourCommonSense it is indeed the COALESCE() function thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` to use the first non-`null` value.

```
select 
    tr.res_id, 
    coalesce(tc.blotter_entry, te.blotter_entry, tv.blotter_entry) as blotter_entry
    tb.blotter_id, 
    tb.blotter_type, 
    tb.blotter_reporteddate, 
    tb.blotter_reportedtime, 
    tb.blotter_incidentdate, 
    tb.blotter_incidenttime, 
    tb.blotter_status, 
    tc.complainant_name, 
    te.respondent_name, 
    tv.victim_name
from tbl_resident tr
left join tbl_complainant tc    on tr.res_id = tc.res_id
left join tbl_respondent te     on tr.res_id = te.res_id
left join tbl_victim tv         on tr.res_id = tv.res_id
left join tbl_blotter tb        on tb.blotter_entry in (tc.blotter_entry, te.blotter_entry, tv.blotter_entry)
where tr.res_id = 1;
```

Notes:

- `res_id` is also ambiguous in the `select` clause; it appears multiple times, from different tables. Since that's the column you are using to `join` and filter, it is sufficient to bring value for the first table in the `from` clause
- I simplified the join condition on the last table to use `in` rather than repeated `or` conditions

Comment: Ok ok. I can see your point there, lemme try this and study ```coalesce()``` function and the use of the use of ```in``` will get back immediately.

Comment: Hello. I studied all night with regards to the functions that can be used in MySQL Queries. It seems that the ```coalesce()``` function is the right answer. Thank you!